# how to display text encoded in ISO-8859 on android device

Tags: android, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I need to display the content from a url in a text view. The content of this url is just plain text (no metadata) in a non-english language. I am reading the content using InputStreamReader with UTF-8 encoding,

```
URL url = new URL(url);
URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        urlConnection.getInputStream(), "Charset.forName(UTF-8"));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
return sb.toString();
```

The text display code :

```
textView.setText(text);
```

But the text appeared all garbled, I googled and finally guessed the text is in ISO-8859_1, so I changed the encoding in the InputStreamReader to ISO-8859_1, but the text still looked garbled.

I googled and finally found that modifying the textView code actually works

```
textView.setText(new String(text.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
```

My question is, 1. why changing the charset in inputStreamReader did not work? 
Also, 2. I do not understand why the text view change worked. The text was read in UTF-8 format, so why are we converting the text into bytes using ISO-8859 and then encoding it again in UTF-8?

Can somebody shed some light on it? Or may be some text that I can read to understand what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The `InputStreamReader` reads bytes from the underlying `InputStream` and tries to decode them using the charset that you provided. What seems to be your issue is that the `InputStream` itself is encoded in UTF-8, which results from the server and your HTTP client agreeing to use it.

So, if you have an ISO-8859-1 string and you sent through this channel then its bytes will be encoded (again) as UTF-8, resulting in the actual message being doubly encoded.

```
bytes = encode(encode("ISO-8859-1", "string"), "UTF-8");
```

In order to decode the string, you must first undo the UTF-8 encoding (via `new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))` and then undo the ISO-8859-1 encoding too via `new String(text.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8")`.

You can probably see that the last step would not be necessary if the original content was already provided in UTF-8, so if you also have access to the server code, you should make it return the data in UTF-8 to avoid the unnecessary work on the client.